# call a js function of a page from another page

Tags: javascript, html

i have this function in the index page which show a part of the the page and hide the other:

```
var switchTab = function() {
    var p = $(this).parent('li');
    var i  = p.index();
    var s = section.eq(i);
    var c = s.find('*');

    section.removeClass('active');
    sectionContent.removeAttr('style');
    s.addClass('active');

    c.css({
        transform: 'none',
        opacity: 1
    });

    linkParent.removeClass('active');
    p.addClass('active');

    return false;
};

link.on('click', switchTab);
</script>
```

now i wanted to jump to a certain part of the page in the index from the menu bar so i used this a href:

```
<li><a href="index.html#offers" onclick="switchTab()">NEWS</a></li>
```

and i as u can see had to use the function to be able to href this part.

the problem is that this works fine in the index page since the function is in the index page, but when i click on the news on the menu bar on another page it just takes me to the index page and not to the part i want in the index page.

is there a way to make it work? any ideas?

note: i tried adding this function to the other pages but still having the same result, i think it is because the function should be called in the index page and it is useless in the other pages.

this are the tabs in the index page, the function closes the old one and open the one i click on, i want to go to one of the tabs in the index page from another page.
[the tabs in the index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI1zh.png)

i want to directly switch to the news tab when the user clicks news in the menu bar in other pages.

is there a way i can write a js that first load the index page than call the function?

Comment: You need to include that code/function snippet on all pages you want to enable the functionality on. Either as an inline chunk, or writing this JS to a file and including the file via "script" tags.

Comment: i already did, but no result because the function should be used when the href take me to the index, the function should work in the index not in the other pages.

Comment: Are you using IFRAMEs within a parent page?

Comment: to do what you want to do the right way is localStorage to fixed value or sessionStorage do an observer to bind this value onchange and then change property between pages... etc

Comment: @headmax can u give an example please

Comment: @محمودياسين give me 10min i need to do something ;).

Comment: @headmax take your time :)

Comment: Just need now 30min to wrote something for the test way.

Comment: @headmax i added an image of the tab and explained what the function does i dont know if this helps to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: @محمودياسين you can't call a function js because the function need to be loaded in the both side the only way to do this is from socket. but you can communicate by using postMessage here a example the end part commented if the page you receive message. https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/WXQXYP

Comment: @محمودياسين just try to adapt to your context and look how we did with this function. Regards.

Comment: ok @headmax, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must create a file javascript like app.js or whatever, then include to script tag like this :

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And inside app.js you can declare your function inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function switchTab() {
var p = $(this).parent('li');
var i  = p.index();
var s = section.eq(i);
var c = s.find('*');

section.removeClass('active');
sectionContent.removeAttr('style');
s.addClass('active');

c.css({
    transform: 'none',
    opacity: 1
});

linkParent.removeClass('active');
p.addClass('active');

return false;
};
});
```

Comment: no, still having the same result. i created a javascrip file and added the function to it as u mentioned and called the file from the other pages but still getting the same result, it only takes me to the index page and not to the part i want.